# Which URL to use to call an API function in symfony from a react component, all in the same app?

Tags: jquery, reactjs, symfony, react-router

I'm developing a web app with Symfony 3.4.* as backend and React in the frontend (also have React-Router, Babel, Browserify, Webpack, Jquery, Bootstrap).

I have a function under `componentWillMount` of one of my react's components, that is responsible to get some data from an API that I expose from the backend (in Symfony), and it works OK, but today I'm using the absolute local url to this API function.

> The Symfony app and the React app are on the same server.

**What changes should I do to use a relative URL of the API function, in order to make the whole app easy deployable on any host?**

```
componentWillMount: function () {
    var items;
    var self = this;
    $.getJSON("http://localhost:8000/api/items", function (data) {
        for (items in data) {
            self.addItem(data[items]);
        }
    });
},
```

## EDIT

I thing this can be achieved using FOSJsRoutingBundle. I prefer simple solutions without use this bundle, but I can accept answers using that anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a sort of

```
 var config =  JSON.stringify(require('./config.prod.json'));
 var endPoint = config.EndPoint;
```

and put your configuration under as JSON.

A more extended answer could be this: 
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1469#issuecomment-290081143

If your client and backend are running on the same server.

just $.getJSON("/api/items") would work

Comment: This may work, but are there some kind of function or method to get the initial or root URL of the app `http://localhost:8000` in JS/React, if this is possible the rest can be concatenable.

Comment: in javascript window.location.host or .hostname . But, in my opinion, your endpoint URL must be under a config file

Comment: If your client and backend are running on the same server  just  $.getJSON("/api/items") would work

Comment: Thanks. This last recomendation works! If you edit your answer with your last comment, you'll get correct answer!

Comment: Done!! . I use nearly the same idea on an angular app running side by side with his backend